# If $x=P(\{1,2\}), y=P(\{2,3\}), z=P(\{1,3\})$, prove that $P$ is countably additive

Tags: probability

> Suppose $\Omega = \{1,2,3\}$, $P(\Phi)= 0 $ and $P(\{1,2,3\})=1$, plus the conditions stated in the title, prove $P$ is countably additive.

My thought is $x \bigcup y \bigcup z $ is $\Omega$, but how to write a rigorous proof for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I am mistaken, but a countably additive set function must be defined on a $\sigma$-algebra. In other words, you need to define $P(\{3\}) = 1-x, P(\{1\}) = 1-y$ and $P(\{2\}) = 1-z$. For this function to be additive, you need that
$$
x = P(\{1,2\}) = 1-y+1-z \Rightarrow x+y+z = 2
$$
Assuming this is true, you can prove finite additivity (case by case, if you wish), which is the same as countable additivity because the set $\Omega$ is finite.